# Fire multiple Fancybox with for loop

Tags: jquery

I have six albums with the following classes: `.fancybox_mygallery_1, .fancybox_mygallery_2, .., .fancybox_mygallery_6`

I am trying to fire multiple Fancybox plugins using this:

```
var mystr = ".fancybox_mygallery_";
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    mystr = mystr + i;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(mystr).fancybox({});
    });
    mystr = ".fancybox_mygallery_";
}
```

However it's not working. I debugged it and it seems that `mystr` has correct value each iteration. What can be the problem?

UPD: From Fancybox page:

> Galleries are created from elements who have the same
>   "data-fancybox-group" or "rel" attribute value.

So I should just give them one of those.

Comment: You should give all of them the *exact* same class and just call `$('.fancybox_gallery').fancybox()` without looping. The whole point of classes is to group elements together.

Comment: Try: `$('[class^="fancybox_mygallery_"]').fancybox();` without the for loop

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, By carrot sign (`^`) you select all classes which started with `fancybox_mygallery_`. And here there is 6 classes which started with `fancybox_mygallery_`. I think you mean `$('[class^=fancybox_mygallery_' + i + ']').fancybox();`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I give them the same class the Fancybox will fo through every image within that class but I have albums, I want the Fancybox to go through images that are within that class only.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi That's exactly what I DON'T mean - the point of the wildcard is to take the loop and thus the `i` out of play

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop use the jQuery wildcard functionality:

```
$('[class^="fancybox_mygallery_"]').fancybox();
```

This targets everything with a class which starts with `fancybox_mygallery_`